# Python regexp which IGNORE newline character

Tags: python, regex

I have text which contains newline character like below. I wondered whether it possible to use Python's regexps which will just ignore newlines like `\n` or `\r` does not exists in string?

For example, in text:

```
s = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore'''
```

find by regexp `/sit amet,consectetur adipisicing/` should return one match.

As I understand re.MULTILINE here in unapplicable and re.DOTALL also because it is just treating dot char as newline also. In my case I do nto want to expand regexp.

NOTE: I cannot just trim newline chars because this text must be saved back.

Answer (score 2):

At first: `/sit amet,consectetur adipisicing/` is not a pattern, it is a fixed sequence of characters. If you would allow newlines between the words, it could become a pattern, but then you need to describe this in your regex.

What you could do is to replace every space in your pattern with `\s+`:

```
 sit\s+amet,\s+consectetur\s+adipisicing
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?385p4)

`\s` is a whitespace character, including `\r` and `\n`, see [python.org](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: +1 for ... \s is a whitespace character, including \r and \n     .... so I had to resort to : + instead of :\s+ to avoid matching newlines.